# firebase and com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I just added firebase support to my android app. At first it worked fine. However, in order to track stacktraces I added the following stuff to my `app/gradle.build`:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
```

such that it looks like this right now:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

However, when I want to start my app now I am getting the following error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.0.
```

I first checked in the SDK manager that everything was up to date and it is:
[image]

Since it did not work, I tried to add the required dependency manually like this:

```
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

Didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure following dependencies are using the same version.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
```